# Improper Prior in Logit and Probit Models: Proper Posterior Conditions

Tags: classification, integral, improper-prior, objective-bayes

Let

$y_i \vert p_i \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p_i)$,

$p_i = F_h(X_i^\prime \beta) \ \ , \ \ h = 1,2 \ ,\  \ X , \beta \in \mathbb R^p$,

where $F_1(x) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^x \exp(-t^2/2) \ dt \ $ and $F_2(x) = \big(1+\exp(-x) \big)^{-1}$.

So if $h=1$ or $h=2$ we have the probit or logit model respectively. In chapter $4$ of book ["Bayesian Core: A Practical Approach to Computational Bayesian Statistics" (Marin and Robert)](http://amzn.to/2kxDAo2) the authors suggest the use of $2$ kind of priors for these models, i.e.

$\pi(\beta) \propto 1 \ $ (flat prior),

$ \beta \vert \sigma^2 \sim N_p \big(0_p, \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1} \big) \, , \, \pi(\sigma^2) \propto \sigma^{-3/2}$ (g-like-prior) .

However both of them are improper, so one needs to check if the posterior is a proper distribution. The authors leave this task as exercise but I do not have any idea to do this. More precisely, I know one needs to prove
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^{p}} \pi(\beta) L(y; \beta) d \beta < \infty \, ,
$$
where $L(y; \beta)$ is the likelihood. I do not know how to find conditions on $(y,X)$ such that $\pi(\beta) L(y; \beta)$ is integrable in the cases of probit and logit likelihood.

So, are there some references (book or papers) that explain and prove the conditions such that $\beta \vert y$ is a proper distribution with the use of flat and g-like-prior under probit and logit models?

Thank you for the help

EDIT:

As suggested by @Xi'an I have tried the latent variable representation, i.e.

$y_i = \mathbb I\{s_i > 0\} \ , \ i = 1,2, \dots, n$ ,

$s = X \beta + \epsilon$ ,

where $\epsilon_i \overset{iid} \sim N(0,1)$ and $\epsilon_i \overset{iid} \sim Logis(0,1)$ in the probit and logit model respectively.

In the case of probit model one has $s \vert \beta \sim N_n(X \beta, I_n)$, so by assuming a flat prior on $\beta$ one has

$$
\pi(s) = \int_{\mathbb R^p} \pi(s \vert \beta) \pi(\beta) d\beta = \int_{\mathbb R^p} (2 \pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \exp \big(-\frac{1}{2} (s - X \beta)^T (s - X \beta) \big) d\beta
$$

with some algebra one obtains

$$
\pi(s) \propto \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} s^T(I_n - X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T)s \Big) \, .
$$

Therefore one needs to check if $\pi(s \vert y) \propto \mathbb  \prod_{i=1}^n I\big( (2y_i-1)s_i \ge 0 \big) \pi(s)$ is integrable.

Let $n_0$ be the number of $y_i$'s equal to $0$, let $n_1$ be the number of $y_i$'s equal to $1$ and let $M = I_n - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, thus
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^{n_0}_-} \int_{\mathbb R^{n_1}_+} \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} s^T M s \Big) ds \, .
$$

Let $A$ a diagonal matrix with entries $A_{ii} = 2y_i-1$, let $s = Au$ thus $\lvert det(A) \rvert = 1$ and the domain of integration of $u$ is the positive orthant of $\mathbb R$, then

$$
\int_{\mathbb R^{n}_+} \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} u^T A M A u \Big) du \, .
$$

since $M$ is a projection matrix it is always diagonalizable and has $n-p$ ones and $p$ zeros as eigenvalues. For the sake of simplicity assume the first $n-p$ are ones, So

$$
\int_{\mathbb R^{n}_+} \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} u^T A M A u \Big) du = \int_{\mathbb R^{n}_+} \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} u^T A PDP^T A u \Big) du \, .
$$

Let $t = P^T A u$ then $\lvert \det AP \rvert = 1$ and the domain of integration is $S(t) = \{t \in \mathbb R^n:APt \ge 0_n\}$, so one has

$$
\int_{S(t)} \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} t^T D t \Big) dt = \int_{S(t)} \exp \Big(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-p} t_i^2 \Big) dt \, .
$$

But from this point I do not know how go on.

Thank you for the help

Comment: You need to prove that$$\int\pi(\beta)f(y|X,\beta)\,\text d\beta<\infty$$for a given sample of $(y_i,X_i)$.

Comment: thank you Xi'an for the answer, the problem is that I am not able to prove the $\pi(\beta) f(y \vert X, \beta)$ is integrable in the cases of probit and logit likelihood

Comment: Try using the latent variables in the model, e.g.$$y_i=\mathbb I_{y_i^*\ge 0}$$

Comment: @Xi'an I have added my try in the case of probit model with flat prior in the first post. However I think I get some errors.

Comment: I found an error, however now I do not know how to complete the exercise